# Passing data from a Pandas Dataframe into a String using the string.format() Method

Tags: python, string, pandas, format

I have a dataframe which includes names, age and score. What I'm trying to do is pass the name, age and score into a message (a string) using the format() method.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df

      A     B      C
0    Matt  23    0.98
1    Mark  34    9.33
2    Luke  52    2.54
3    John  67    4.73
```

The message I want to pass this data into:

```
message = "{} is {} years old and has a score of {}"
```

My limited understanding of using the .format() method with the message (string)

```
message.format()
```

From what I can tell, I need to have the dataframe as 1 of the arguments for the format() method, butother than that, I'm unsure as to how to code this up.

Help/assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Matt',23,0.98],['Mark',34,0.43]])
message = "{} is {} years old and has a score of {}"
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    print(message.format(*r.to_dict().values()))
```

Output:

```
Matt is 23 years old and has a score of 0.98
Mark is 34 years old and has a score of 0.43
```