# Passing Data from a Database to an HTML file

Tags: python, sql, string, pandas, format

I asked a similar question to this earlier ([Passing data from a Pandas Dataframe into a String using the string.format() Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58623743/passing-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-string-using-the-string-format-met)).

What I'd like to do is replicate the approach but taking the data from a database, which is stored as dataframe, and then placing the data into a string, which is basically an HTML file. I'm assuming it doesn't matter its an HTML file, as its just a string..? The data needs to be placed inside the header tags {} in the string.

Approach so far. Note: I haven't included the whole HTML file as its pretty big.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_sql('select * from "HUMANS".people_info Limit 100', con = engine )

test = """

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1>{}</h1>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>

df1 = df['Names']


for i, r in df1.items():
    test.format(*r.to_dict().values())
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
```

Could anyone suggest a way of passing the data from the DB to string?

Comment: `r` is a string that doesn't know anything about `.to_dict()`. Maybe just print `r`, to see what it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone might find themselves in a similar situation, I finally got there:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_sql('select * from "HUMANS".people_info Limit 100', con = engine )

test = """

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1>{}</h1>

    </div>

   </body>
</html>

df1 = df.filter['Names'] #persons name will be placed in HTML file
file = ""

for i, rows in df1.iterrows():
    name = (df1['Names'][i])

    with open(f"people{i}.html", "w") as file:
         file.write(test.format(name))
         file.close()
```

This will produce 100 HTML files containing names taken from the DB